# Create structs with names generated at runtime and refer to them within program

Tags: c++, struct, runtime

I have a set of datafiles stored within a directory.
eg.

```
./FT/Fourier_1
./FT/Fourier_2
./FT/Fourier_3
...
```

My code initially generates a list of the paths to these files.

```
std::string fileStringSearch="Fourier";
std::stringstream resultFileName;
std::vector<std::string> fileList;
int numLines=0;

DIR *parentDirPointer;
struct dirent *dp;

if ((parentDirPointer = opendir("FT")) == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open the parent (FT) directory" << std::endl;
    return(3);
}

while ((dp = readdir(parentDirPointer)) != NULL)
{
    std::string testFileName = dp->d_name;
    if (testFileName.find(fileStringSearch) != std::string::npos)
    {
        resultFileName << "FT/" << dp->d_name;
        std::string blahblah=resultFileName.str();
        fileList.push_back(blahblah);
        numLines++;
        resultFileName.str(std::string());
        resultFileName.clear();
    }
};

sort(fileList.begin(),fileList.end());

for (unsigned n=0; n<fileList.size(); ++n)
{
    resultFileName << fileList.at(n) << std::endl;
}
FTFilePaths = resultFileName.str();
```

I then want to read data from each file and store it in some format which I can later read, use in functions, etc.

My current thought is a struct - I have:

```
struct Wavenum_struct {
    std::string name;
    double timestep;
    double indexToK_Multiplier;
    std::vector<double> Amp_k;
    std::vector<double> dFTdt_prev_to_this;
    }
```

and at a later point in my program I read these files like :

```
for (int lineCounter=0; lineCounter < numLines; lineCounter++)
    {
        getline(readPath, FilePathLine);
        c = FilePathLine.c_str();
        readFile.open(c);
        extern Wavenum_struct c;
        c.name = FilePathLine;
        //print_name(c);
        while(getline (readFile, lineToRead))
        {
            readFile >> value;
            c.Amp_k.push_back(value);
        }
        //print_amps(c);

    }
```

The commented out print_amps(c); will work just fine with a function something like:

```
void print_amps(struct Wavenum_struct t)
{
    for(int i=0; i<t.Amp_k.size(); i++)
    {   
        std::cout << i << ": " << t.Amp_k[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but this obviously prints the amplitudes of every struct, and only once. If I want to refer to specific structs later in the program, and print them selectively, (or not print them, but use them for some function) eg

```
void dFTdt(struct Wavenum_struct t_i, struct Wavenum_struct t_i1)
{
    int numWavenums = t_i.Amp_k.size();
    double dt = t_i1.timestep - t_i.timestep;
    double dFTdt[numWavenums];
    for (int k=0; k<numWavenums; k++)
    {
        dFTdt[k] = (t_i1.Amp_k[k] - t_i.Amp_k[k])/dt;
    }
    t_i1.dFTdt_prev_to_this.assign(dFTdt, dFTdt+numWavenums);
}
```

then I can't seem to get anywhere, since c returns to being recognised as a const * char outside of the for loop, and anything I've tried like:

```
print_amps(reinterpret_cast<Wavenum_struct*>("FT/Fourier_1"));
```

refuses to compile.

I assume that what I need might involve pointers to functions and print_name() as a function of the struct, but this doesn't seem likely to help me with my void dFTdt() function, and I still don't know how to refer to a given struct once c no longer gives the name of that struct.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: `extern Wavenum_struct c;` Why `extern`? Also you are redeclaring `c` there. You don't need the `struct` keyword everywhere (only in the definition of `Wavenum_struct`). Why don't you just use a `vector<Wavenum_struct>` to store all file data? I do not understand what that has to do with type names at all.

Comment: Ah, that was a later effort to make the name of the struct possible to refer to - originally there was no `extern`. As to redeclaring `c`, I suspect that's where my problem lies, since it becomes impossible (I think?) to refer back to it later. I'll remove the `struct` from `(struct Wavenum_struct t)` etc - thank you. For the "Why don't you just use a `vector<Wavenum_struct>` to store all file data" do you mean in some way instead of the `readFile >> value; c.Amp_k.push_back(value);` section?

Comment: @Beta outlined the use of a `vector<Wavenum_struct>` in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function (which really should have a name):

```
for (int lineCounter=0; lineCounter < numLines; lineCounter++)
{
  getline(readPath, FilePathLine);
  c = FilePathLine.c_str();
  readFile.open(c);
  extern Wavenum_struct c;
  c.name = FilePathLine;
  //print_name(c);
  while(getline (readFile, lineToRead))
  {
      readFile >> value;
      c.Amp_k.push_back(value);
  }
  //print_amps(c);
}
```

apart from the fact that you appear to be reusing the variable name "c" (which is unseemly), your `Wavenum_struct c` gets overwritten with each iteration through the loop, so even if you have this "extern" set up correctly, the most you will retain is the last one. You have to save these Wavenums somewhere, so why not use a `vector`?

```
std::vector<Wavenum_struct> wavenums;
for (int lineCounter=0; lineCounter < numLines; lineCounter++)
{
  ...
  //print_amps(c);
  wavenums.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: This allows me to later use `wavenums[value between 0 and numLines].print_name();` if struct contains the function `void print_name()
    {
        std::cout << "The name of this struct is: " << this->name << std::endl;
    }` - thank you :)